# A variant of Lambert function

Tags: nt.number-theory, special-functions

How to express the solution of $x^{x+1}=a$ using Lambert function? I know that the standard Lambert function can be used to describe the solution of $x^x=a$. I wonder if $x^{x+1}=a$ can be addressed similarly.

Answer (score 12):

Sorry, my answer is **wrong**. As it was pointed out by "Simply Beautiful Art" $x\ne W(z)$ but $x=e^{W(z)}.$

It is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Derivative) that $$W'(z)=\frac{W(z)}{z(1+W(z))}.$$
Let $z=\log t$. Then $x=W(z)$ is a root of the equation $x^x=t$, in particular $x\log x=\log t=z.$ It means that $$W'(z)=\frac{x}{(x+1)\log t}=\frac{1}{(x+1)\log x}=\frac{1}{\log x^{x+1}},\quad x^{x+1}=e^{\frac{1}{W'(z)}}.$$
So solution of the equation $x^{x+1}=a$ is $x=W(z)$, where $z$ is defined by $W'(z)=1/\log a.$

Comment: What about if $x$ is in the denominator, i.e., how to solve $\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^{x+1}=b$? Thank you

Comment: @lchen It is not clear.

Comment: Ｉmean to solve the equation $\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^{x+1}=b$.

Comment: @lchen I don't know.

Comment: Thank you all the same. I thought that it was related to Lambert function but could not figure out the solution.

Comment: @lchen If you'll replace $x$ by $-x$ and $a$ by $-a$, then you'll get $\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^{x-1}=b.$

Comment: Huh I've never thought to use the derivative of the Lambert W function, interesting approach.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if $z=\ln(t)$ and $x=W(z)$, then $z=xe^x$ and $t=e^z=e^{xe^x}\ne x^x$.

Comment: Assuming I haven't made a mistake, using this approach but modified with $\ln(x)=W(z)$ will give us $$W'(z)=\frac1{x(\ln(x)+1)}$$which is reduces to$$\frac e{ex\ln(ex)}$$which is invertible using the Lambert W function. It does go to show, however, that the inverse of $W'$ is solvable in terms of $W$ and is given by$$(W')^{-1}(z)=x\ln(x),~x=\frac e{W^{-1}(\ln(z)+1)}$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt You are write, my answer is wrong.

Comment: Thank you both.